# Android swipe view custom tabs

Tags: android, menu, tabs, fragment, swipe

I want to make an app in which you can swipe the fragments. The tab host should be at the bottom and instead of text I want some imageviews. Fragments should be selected by swipe or by clicking an image from the bottom. And if have have a lot of fragments I was wondering if I can add the tab host to a horizontal scrollview.
Any adivce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strongly recommending Jake Wharton's open project: Android ViewPageIndicator. Link is: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

You can try the demo first. The demo link is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viewpagerindicator.sample